# Apache Felix and OSGi

Tags: osgi, apache-felix, eclipse-mars

On installing BndTools for Code for Apache Felix using OSGi getting this error :

The selected wizard could not be started. Plug-in "bndtools.core" was unable to instantiate class "bndtools.wizards.project.NewBndProjectWizardFactory". org/eclipse/jdt/ui/wizards/NewJavaProjectWizardPageOne

I'm installing this tool in Eclipse Mars.

Comment: Please can any1 reply if know the answer..

Comment: This is clearly a bug. Please could you report it against the [Bndtools bug tracker](https://github.com/bndtools/bndtools/issues), including the version of Bndtools you are using.